# ¿Cómo hacer un botón que me direccione a mi mismo código?

Tags: html, html5, enlaces-ancla

**HTML/HTML5 
Hola, soy nuevo en esto del diseño web. Quiero hacer un botón que me redireccione a mi mismo código en: Título1 <--(un relato). Y al presionar "Título1" que me redireccione a "Título2" donde contiene las fotos.

Título2 fotos ** así sea fotos o más texto, que necesito las dos.

Sería como un enlace a mi mismo código... Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Agrega por favor tu código

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar una id al elemento que deseas redireccionar y por ejemplo en en la imagen que te redireccionar al título del relato sería algo asi

```
<h1 id="titulo1" >Titulo1</h1>


<a href="#titulo1" ><img></a>
```

Ahora solo agregar la etiqueta `<a>` con el atributo `href` y la id del elemento a donde quieres que te redireccione

Comment: Mil gracias por la ayuda!